# How to filter duplicates in an RDD scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, rdd

I have an rdd with different fields namely a, b, c, d. I would like to filter on one of the field which has duplicate values in it.
For example

```
inputRdd = [(1,2,3,4), (1,2,4,5), (2,3,4,5), (2,6,4,8), (2,0,3,7), (3,5,6,7), (9,1,5,6)]

resultRdd = [(1,2,3,4), (1,2,4,5), (2,3,4,5), (2,6,4,8), (2,0,3,7)]
```

is there a function that I can apply to do this?

something like

```
resultRDD = inputRdd.filter(x => x.a.contains("identify duplicates"))
```

Comment: How are (3,5,6,7), (9,1,5,6) duplicates?

Comment: @Lars Skaug That's just my input. I left those out in my resultRdd.

Comment: Please define a duplicate and update your post with representative data and expected result according to the data you provide.

Comment: what about `inputRdd.distinct` ?

Comment: I don't want distinct. I want repeated elements in first position.